# php send email with image

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, email, sendmail

I am trying to send an email with a picture; the body of my email is:

```
<?php 

$message = <<< email

<img src="http://planet-earth.bogus.us/icons/secret.pictures.gif">

Dear {$email},

email;

?>
```

When I receive the email, I can't see the picture. Instead, I 
see `<img src="http://planet-earth.bogus.us/icons/secret.pictures.gif">`. I know it's because of the <<< email; how would I be able to display the picture instead of the code using <<< email?

UPDATE

I am using zend-framework. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
     $mail = new Zend_Mail();
     $mail->setFrom('admin@mysite.com', 'My site');
     $mail->addTo($recoveryaccount->username);
     $mail->setSubject("Mysite");
     include "_email_recover_password.phtml";
     $mail->setBodyText($message);
     $mail->send();
?>

_include "_email_recover_password.pthml" 
<?php 

 $message = <<< email
 <img src="http://picturelocation.picture.gif">
 Dear {$account->getUsername()},

 Somebody has requested that the password associated with this account be
 reset. If you initiated this request, click the below link to complete the process:

 http://www.example.com/{$account->getRecovery()}

 Thank you!
 Mysite

 Questions? Contact us at admin@mysite.com

 email;

 ?>
```

Comment: No, it actually has nothing to do with the `<<< email` and more to do with your content type. Can you show the code where you send the e-mail please?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question, you need to send out content headers that sets the content type to `text\html`. Without it, your message is treated as plain text by the receiving client. The following code sets the content headers properly and sends out a basic HTML message.

```
// message
$message = '
<html>
<body>
  <img src="http://planet-earth.bogus.us/icons/secret.pictures.gif">
</body>
</html>
';

// Add the content headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'To: David <david-z@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Bot <bot@domain.com>' . "\r\n";

mail("david-z@domain.com", "mysubject", $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not because of the heredoc. You need to send a properly formatted HTML mail, which you aren't. There's various headers and MIME 'skeleton' structural stuff that you're not sending at all.

Don't try to build one yourself. Use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) to do that for you.

Answer (score -1):

What i use ,

```
$from="From: TEST\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"; 
mail("TOWHO@TEST.com", $title, $content, $from);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.